# Retrieving value from row on click on button in grid React MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

A project I am involved with has a react user grid component. The grid is populated by requesting data from the server. When I click on a button in a grid row, I need to get the value of the `"_id"` field of this particular row.
I only managed to get the `_id` of all rows, but I only need the value of the row where the button was clicked. In addition, the button click event occurs immediately on page load, not just on click.
[image]

```
    const columns = [
  {
    field: '_id', headerName: 'id', type: 'number', flex: 0.9,
  },
  {
    field: 'userName', headerName: 'Username', flex: 0.7,
  },
  {
    field: 'email', headerName: 'email', flex: 0.7,
  },
  {
    field: 'fullName', headerName: 'Full name', flex: 0.7,
  },
  {
    field: 'status', headerName: 'Status', flex: 0.7,
  },
  {
    field: 'actions',
    type: 'actions',
    headerName: 'Actions',
    flex: 0.2,
    getActions: (params) => [
      <IconButton onClick={console.log(params.row._id)}>
        <EditIcon />
      </IconButton>,
    ],
  },
];

function generateRows(users) {
  return users.map((user) => (({
    _id, userName, email, fullName, status,
  }) => ({
    _id, userName, email, fullName, status,
  }))(user));
}

export default function UserControlTable() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    users: [],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      const users = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + USER_LIST);
      setData({ users: generateRows(users.data)});
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Container>
      <DataGrid
        getRowId={(row) => row._id}
        rows={data.users}
        columns={columns}
        checkboxSelection
        column
      />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: try `onClick={() => console.log(params.row._id)}` You have to return an arrow function inside the onClick. I'm surprised your editor doesn't complain about assigning console.log inside the onClick handler.

Comment: @SakisTsalk, Yes your answer works, thanks for that. And of course my editor swears about calling the console, I only use it for debugging. Post your answer and I will mark it with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like my comment above try:

```
onClick={() => console.log(params.row._id)}
```

instead of

```
onClick={console.log(params.row._id)}
```

You have to return an arrow function inside the `onClick` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve the click event on Grid:

```
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';

const handleGridClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
  console.log('Grid click');
  console.log(event);
}


export default function ClickableGrid() {
  return (
    <Grid onClick={handleBoxClick}>
         // Rest of the codes
    </Grid>
  );
}
```